# What does the last ayah in Sura Alaq mean?

Tags: quran, tafseer, uloom-al-quran

What i don't understand is, why Allah S.W.T said Do not obey him in the ayah. I'm so confused here. Sorry for bad English.

> [Quran 96:19](https://quran.com/96/19) " No! Do not obey him. But prostrate and draw near [to God] "

Comment: https://quran.com/96/16 is "A lying, sinful forelock!" please edit/correct the verse

Comment: In addition to [edit]ing to fix the bug Honey points out; would it be possible to identify precisely what you don't understand?  (And welcome to Islam.SE!)

Comment: you can see other translations: http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/96/19/default.htm , and also in quran.com.

Comment: @Honey he is talking about 96:19 not 96:16. You got mistaken.

Comment: @Armaan The question was initially referencing the wrong verse.

Answer (score 2):

To find out what this verse means, we must look at the other verses of [Surah Alaq](https://quran.com/96/):

```
Recite in the name of your Lord who created 
Created man from a clinging substance.
Recite, and your Lord is the most Generous
Who taught by the pen
Taught man that which he knew not.

No! [But] indeed, man transgresses
Because he sees himself self-sufficient.
Indeed, to your Lord is the return.

Have you seen the one who forbids
A servant when he prays?
Have you seen if he is upon guidance
Or enjoins righteousness?
Have you seen if he denies and turns away -
Does he not know that Allah sees?

No! If he does not desist, We will surely drag him by the forelock -
A lying, sinning forelock.
Then let him call his associates;
We will call the angels of Hell.
No! Do not obey him. But prostrate and draw near [to Allah].
```

In these verses, it is talking about [Abu Jahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amr_ibn_Hish%C4%81m) threatening and trying to prevent Prophet Muhammad from praying the Islamic way in the Ka'bah. This is when the 2nd part of the Surah was revealed. Then when it says 'let him call his associates', it is taking about Abu Jahl's supporters which the 'angels of Hell' will deal with.

Then the verse you were talking about:
Quran 96:19 " No! Do not obey him. But prostrate and draw near [to God] "

It is saying to ignore those who try to prevent you from praying Salah and when it says,' prostrate and draw near', it is talking about to keep praying Salah and go closer to Allah.

Comment: thank you for your explanation...now it's clear to me...Nevertheless, i found that this ayah is so beautiful...especially on the part that says " No! [But] indeed, man transgresses Because he sees himself self-sufficient " ...thank you again and have good day :)